# How to merge sets using java stream?

Tags: java, merge, set, java-stream

I have two `Set`s like this：

```
Set<String> set1;
Set<String> set2;
```

And I want to merge them with

```
Set<String> s = Stream.of(set1, set2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but I get the following error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that `Set<String>` conforms to `String`
>
> inference variable `T` has incompatible bounds:
>
> equality constraints: `String` lower bounds: `Set<String>`

[image: compilation error]

How can I convert the `Set`s to a single `Set<String>` with `flatMap()`?
Is there any other solution that can accomplish this operation gracefully?

Comment: You need to flatten your stream of sets into a stream of strings

Comment: Why do you need a stream for that? Did you try using the `addAll()` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you insist on using `Stream`s, you can use `flatMap` to convert your `Stream<Set<String>>` to a `Stream<String>`, which can be collected into a `Set<String>`:

```
Set<String> s = Stream.of(set1, set2).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Stream.concat` to merge the stream of two sets and collect as set.

```
Set<String> s = Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of approach possible -

***Concat***

```
Set<String> s = Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It's get slightly ugly for more than 2 streams as we have to write

```
Stream.concat(Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream()), set3.stream())
```

**Concat could be a problem for deeply concatenated stream**. From documentation -

> Use caution when constructing streams from repeated
> concatenation.Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can
> result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException.

***Reduce***

Reduce can also be used to perform concatenation of stream as -

```
Set<String> s = Stream.of(set1.stream(), set2.stream()).reduce(Stream::concat)
  .orElseGet(Stream::empty).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Here `Stream.reduce(`) returns optional that's the reason for `orElseGet` method call. It's also possible to contact multiple set as

```
Stream.of(set1.stream(), set2.stream(), set2.stream()).reduce(Stream::concat).orElseGet(Stream::empty).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Problem associated with deeply contacted stream applies to reduce as well

***Flatmap***

Flatmap can be used to get same result as -

```
 Set<String> s = Stream.of(set1, set2).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

To concat multiple stream you can use -

```
Set<String> s = Stream.of(set1, set2, set3).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

flatmap avoids `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Does `concat()` offer any benefits over `flatMap()` if one disregards the risk of a StackOverflowException?